# VS2010: Add Reference dialog does not open

Tags: visual-studio-2010

On a couple of machines in the office the "Add Reference" dialog in Visual Studio 2010 does not open. There is a flash onscreen which might indicate it opens and then closes immediately. Either way, we can't add references on these machines.

We tried "Tools->Import Export Settings->Reset All Settings" but that didn't work either.

Any ideas?

EDIT: A complete uninstall and reinstall seems to have fixed the issue on at least one machine.
EDIT2: It was a Wacom tablet driver causing the trouble.

Comment: Have you tried a Repair from Control Panel -> Add Remove Programs? Also, are the user's on the effected machines in the VS Debuggers Groups or have elevated privileges (e.g. Power Users or Local Admin's) on the machine?

Comment: VS2010 iterates available references in a worker thread.  Sounds like it is dying, perhaps while encountering an odd-ball one.  Use SysInternals' ProcMon to find the troublemaker.

Comment: @dash, repair didn't work. But a full uninstall/reinstall fixed it.

Comment: @hans passant, we still have one more machine causing problems, I'm going to try ProcMon to isolate it further. Thanks for the help folks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both machines had WACOM tablet software installed for the artists Centiq's. Removing the Wacom tablet drivers and software fixed the problem immediately.

So no more artists with Visual Studio! And no more programmers with tablets!